# How to convert List of Map into Map of List using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have `List` of `Map`s as

```
[{"a"="10","b"="20"},{"a"="12","b"="22"},{"a"="14","b"="24"}]
```

And I want a `Map` as

```
{"a"=["10","12","14"],"b"=["20","22","24"]}
```

Comment: Are the keys chars and the values ints?

Comment: In my case both are strings.

Comment: There is no research effort about the question and no effort of solve this problem from OP, still  people are answering such a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this without having to instantiate an additional data structure. You first map the `Map`s to `Map.Entry` and then group by key.

```java
var listOfMaps = List.of(
        Map.of("a", 10, "b", 20),
        Map.of("a", 12, "b", 22),
        Map.of("a", 14, "b", 24)
);

var mapOfLists = listOfMaps.stream()
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        Collectors.toList()
                )
        ));

System.out.println(mapOfLists);
```

**Output:**
`{a=[10, 12, 14], b=[20, 22, 24]}`

Comment: It would be nicer to use static imports to avoid verbosity

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of Group By to achieve this. Here is an example.

First we take a stream of list using `list.stream()` and then we make a stream of each Map's Entry using `flatMap`. Now that we have a stream of each Entry(Key-value pair), we use `groupingBy` to collect them as a group.

First argument of `groupingBy` is functions what derive the key , Second argument is optional its a map factory which will be used to create the map, in case you want to have a sorted map you can use `TreeMap::new` , Now third param is reducer part where you tell what will be the grouped value and how it has to be collected(in our case we want it into a list)

```
Map<String, String> ma = new java.util.HashMap<>();
    ma.put("a", "10");
    ma.put("b", "20");
    Map<String, String> ma3 = new java.util.HashMap<>();
    ma3.put("a", "15");
    ma3.put("b", "17");
    ma3.put("c", "19");

    List<Map<String, String>> list = Arrays.asList(ma, ma3);

    Map<String, List<String>> lm = list.stream().flatMap(x -> x.entrySet().stream()).collect(Collectors
            .groupingBy(Entry::getKey, HashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(lm);
```

Output looks like

```
{a=[10, 15], b=[20, 17], c=[19]}
```

Answer (score 3):

```java
Map<String,List<String>> map=new HashMap<>();
list.stream().flatMap(map->map.entrySet().stream()).forEach(entry->{
    map.putIfAbsent(entry.getKey(),new ArrayList<>());
    map.get(entry.getKey()).add(entry.getValue());
});
```

It is not a one-liner because I needed two statements in the `forEach` and I don't like to put something like that in one line but the OP did not ask for a one-liner.

It gets all entries of the inner `Map` as a `Stream` at first (`flatMap`).

After that, it iterates over them doing two actions:

- If no `List` exists for the entry value, a new one is added.
- The value of the entry is added to the inner list of the entry.

Comment: Bad logic, creating a lot of unnecessary `ArrayList` instances. The code should be using `computeIfAbsent()` instead. --- Also, using `forEach()` like this is bad stream logic. Code should be using `collect()` instead. --- It think this is a great example of how *not* to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the remapping function in `Map#merge`.

```
final Map<String,List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
maps.forEach(map -> map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> 
    result.merge(entry.getKey(), Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()), 
        (a,b)->Stream.concat(a.stream(),b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

Comment: In stream logic, the appropriate way is to use `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...))` instead of a stateful `forEach(...)` like that, as shown in this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318289/5221149).